# Vectors with constant angle between any two of them.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

In $m$-dimensional Euclidean space, $n$ distinct unit vectors are to be chosen such that the angle between any two vectors is $\theta$. Prove that

(a) $m \geq n-1$

(b) for $m=n-1$, sum of all the vectors is a null vector, and
\begin{equation}
\cos \theta = -\frac{1}{n-1}
\end{equation}

I am not completely sure that the above statements are actually true. Any help in proving the above will be appreciated.